# How make your image-logo be in a center of your login/register page?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have this logic below for the image, the image should display within a center but now it does not do that at all. What exactly am i doing wrong to this code below? Please help me to improve this logic even better for the purpose of user readability. Or how do i make the logo to display and be in the center? when my login or register page loads to the browser? Please advice me so can make necessary changes.

```
@using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models
@model RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_RegisterLayout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo-switch col-sm-12 text-center col-md-12">
        <img src="~/Images/eNtsa.png" /> // This is not visible at all and want it to be visible to the center to have company logo
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="register-logo">
            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Login")"><b>eNtsa</b> Registration</a>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "firstName", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Full name", required = "required" })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new
                            {
                                @class = "form-control",
                                type = "email",
                                id = "inputEmail",
                                placeholder = "Email address",
                                required = "required",
                                pattern = @"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$",
                                title = "Enter valid email (eg. example@example.com)"
                            })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new
                                    {
                                        @class = "form-control",
                                        type = "password",
                                        id = "inputPassword",
                                        placeholder = "Password",
                                        required = "required",
                                        pattern = @"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}",
                                        title = "Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"
                                    })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", type = "password", id = "confirmPassword", placeholder = "Retype password", required = "required" })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="icheck-primary">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="agreeTerms" name="terms" value="agree">
                                <label for="agreeTerms">
                                    I agree to the <a href="https://entsa.mandela.ac.za/Terms-Conditions">terms</a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
                    <section id="socialLoginForm">
                        @* @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })*@
                    </section>
                </div>
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Login")" class="text-center">I already have a membership</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-danger" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content bg-danger">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Authentication Failed !</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-success" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content bg-success">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Registration</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>User registered successfully. Please check your mail to activate your account.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/">OK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Javascript error handling-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowErrorPopup() {
        $("#modal-danger").modal();
    }
    function ShowSuccessPopup() {
        $("#modal-success").modal();
    }

 </script>
@if(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction !=null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction)
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Noticed the first div push the child aside and scewed them far from each other, made the image to belog inside the second div element. See what i did.

```
@using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models
@model RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_RegisterLayout.cshtml";
}


    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="register-logo">
            <img src="~/Images/eNtsa.png" />
            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Login")"><b>eNtsa</b> Registration</a>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "firstName", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Full name", required = "required" })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new
                            {
                                @class = "form-control",
                                type = "email",
                                id = "inputEmail",
                                placeholder = "Email address",
                                required = "required",
                                pattern = @"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$",
                                title = "Enter valid email (eg. example@example.com)"
                            })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new
                                    {
                                        @class = "form-control",
                                        type = "password",
                                        id = "inputPassword",
                                        placeholder = "Password",
                                        required = "required",
                                        pattern = @"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}",
                                        title = "Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"
                                    })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", type = "password", id = "confirmPassword", placeholder = "Retype password", required = "required" })
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="icheck-primary">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="agreeTerms" name="terms" value="agree">
                                <label for="agreeTerms">
                                    I agree to the <a href="https://entsa.mandela.ac.za/Terms-Conditions">terms</a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
                    <section id="socialLoginForm">
                        @* @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })*@
                    </section>
                </div>
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Login")" class="text-center">I already have a membership</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-danger" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content bg-danger">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Authentication Failed !</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-success" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content bg-success">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Registration</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>User registered successfully. Please check your mail to activate your account.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/">OK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Javascript error handling-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowErrorPopup() {
        $("#modal-danger").modal();
    }
    function ShowSuccessPopup() {
        $("#modal-success").modal();
    }

 </script>
@if(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction !=null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction)
    </script>
}
```